# Complex exponential inequality series proof

Tags: complex-analysis

We know that $|\sum a_n|\leq \sum |a_n|$

So how do we prove that $|e^z-1|\leq e^{|z|}-1\leq |z|e^{|z|}$ ?

Do I find the power series first? i.e.

$|e^z-1| = |\sum \frac{z^n}{n!} -1| \leq  \sum \frac{|z|^n}{n!} -1 \leq |z|\sum \frac{|z|^n}{n!}$ ?

I'm note even sure about this. Could someone derive this clearly?

As well as $(3-e)|z|\leq |e^z-1| \leq (e-1)|z|$ ?

I could attempt: $(3-\sum \frac{1}{n!})|z| \leq  |\sum \frac{z^n}{n!} -1| \leq  (\sum \frac{1}{n!}-1)|z|$, but I'm stuck...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $e^z = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}$ we have

$$|e^z-1| 
= |\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}|
\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|z|^n}{n!} 
= -1+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{|z|^n}{n!} 
= -1 + e^{|z|}$$
and
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|z|^n}{n!} = |z|\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|z|^{n-1}}{n!}
= |z|\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{|z|^{n}}{(n+1)!}
\leq |z|\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{|z|^{n}}{n!}
= |z|e^{|z|}.
$$

Comment: ok thanks, but do we just ignore the 1 on the first expression then? as per your derivation?

Comment: @rebc null pulled out the zeroth term in the series

Comment: Nothing is ignored. $e^z = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!} = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}$. Note we start at $n=1$ instead of $n=0$ and then add the first term separately.

Comment: ooohhh i see....

Comment: thanks @nullUser, could you also help me out with inequality 2? kinda stuck...

Comment: Your second inequality can't be right. You are trying to bound $e^z$ by a polynomial.

Comment: @nullUser sorry it's $z$ in a closed disk $\bar{D}(0;1)$...